# At "a graduate level", "graduate level", or "the graduate level"?

Tags: articles

Do you need to use an article either **a** or **the** before **graduate level** in the following sentence?

> I understand that studying any course at graduate level requires a
> tremendous amount of dedication and hard work.

Comment: You need to come up with some examples.